# How to install a python package into an Virtual Environment without activating it?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

Is it possible to install a python package into a virtual environment without activating it?
Imagine you just wish to update a virtual environment without activating it and install the package in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `python` from a virtual environment without activating the environment. For example if a virtual environment was created at `/some/path/to/venv` use `/some/path/to/venv/bin/python` — the program notices it's in a virtual environment and acts as if the environment is activated. To install a package run

```
/some/path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip install -U package_name
```

Comment: Awsome that is exactly what i NEEded.

Comment: Confirm it works. Any reference to the Python documentation?

Comment: @Dante [`venv` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work), [PEP 405 – Python Virtual Environments](https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/#specification).

Comment: There is also a pip binary in the venv so this can be even shorter:
`/some/path/to/venv/bin/pip install package_name`

Comment: @MaartenDerickx That could fail if `/some/path/to/venv/bin/pip` has `#! /usr/bin/env python` shebang.

Comment: I don't know for different python versions. But the venv module in python3.11 creates the pip files with `#!/some/path/to/venv/bin/python`.